# How to Hide/Show Customer attribute based on customer group in Admin panel Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, admin-panel, customer-attribute, magento-2.2.5

**How to Hide/Show Customer attribute when the customer group is switched from general to the wholesale group?.**

[image]

Comment: any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, firstly you have to create a component for Customer group.

With "initialize" function, you can check the value on page load. If group is "Wholesale", then show the attribute else keep it hidden.

For detecting change event, "onUpdate" function will be used. You can show the attribute using jQuery after detecting the value.